# TestComplete moving Focus

Tags: testcomplete

I'm getting stuck on this problem where when I click the 'Select Product' button a window will appear, (the previous window gets disabled until I add a product) and in it I have to select an item in that window and click the ADD button.

The problem is when TestComplete clicks the 'Select Product' the new window opens (and the old window is disabled until the product is added) and the Testcomplete focus is not moving to that new window.

I don't know how to do that, can you guys help me on it?

Comment: try recording it using key word test and convert it to script, so that you can check how to change focus

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are facing a deadlock: TestComplete waits until the action invoked by the button pressing is completed while it cannot be completely until TestComplete closes the new window. To avoid the deadlock, you need to call the ClickButton method asynchronously. You can find information on how to do this in the [Calling Methods Asynchronously](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31395/) help topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding with JScript do a

```
NameMapping.Sys.TestedApplication.RefreshMappingInfo();
```

This helped in my case accessing controls in a dialog.